# DOT graph from superstate to substate

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'd like to generate the DOT code to draw the equivalent state machine diagram shown.
I going to be created programmatically, I've got the transitions between states and superstates done. ButI need a bit of help with this:

[image: Example state machine diagram]

This gives me an initial transition, but the State1 should be the cluster:

```
digraph {
compound=true;
node [shape=Mrecord]
rankdir="LR"

subgraph clusterOpen
        {
        label = "State1"
        State2
}

State1 -> State2 [style="solid"];
 node [shape = point label="" ] i ->State1
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have so far and where you have problems.

Comment: @albert, I've added what I got so far for the initial transition.

Comment: The name of the cluster is clusterOpen, not State1- State1 is just the label.  You meant this:State1 -> State2 [style="solid"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Graphviz programs try hard to avoid placing nodes on top of other nodes.  But you can place nodes anywhere you like if you explicitly provide a **pos** attribute for each node (see https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords).
The program that creates your input files should calculate a **pos** attribute for each node.  (Remember that **pos** coordinates are in *points*, while node sizes are in *inches*!).  You can probably skip calculating the splines for the edges and just let **neato** do that.
This program:

```
digraph {
    graph [bb="0,0,482.8,337"];
    node [label="\N"];
    State1   [height=4.0139,
        label="{State 1|\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n}",
        pos="162,144.5",
        shape=Mrecord,
        width=4.5];
    State2   [height=1.3333,
        label="{State 2|\n\n\n\n}",
//      pos="403,144.5",
        pos="220,88",
        shape=Mrecord,
        width=1.6944];
    xp3  [height=0.05,
        label="",
//      pos="429,331",
        pos="0,194",
        shape=point,
//      style=dotted,
        style=invis,
        width=0.05];
    r1   [height=0.16667,
        label="",
//      pos="455,331",
        pos="154,194",
        shape=square,
        width=0.16667];
    xp4  [height=0.05,
        label="",
//      pos="481,331",
        pos="0,88",
        shape=point,
//      style=dotted,
        style=invis,
        width=0.05];
    xp1  [height=0.16,
        label="",
        pos="162,331",
        shape=point,
        width=0.16];
    xp1 -> State1:n  [pos="e,162,288.5 162,325.23 162,319.09 162,308.89 162,298.63",
        style=dashed];
    xp2  [height=0.16,
        label="",
//      pos="403,331",
        pos="220,194",
        shape=point,
        width=0.16];
    xp2 -> State2:n  [pos="e,403,192.5 403,325.19 403,307.39 403,251.8 403,202.57"];

// manually added:
  xp3 -> r1      [label="Trigger 1" dir=none ]    
  xp4 -> State2  [label="Trigger 2"  ]    
}
```

Run with this command line:
**neato -n -Tpng stateDiagram.dot >stateDiagram.png**

Produces this graph:
[image]

Comment: It's so beautiful!

Comment: When I run it at http://www.webgraphviz.com/ the boxes are not inside each other ???

Comment: webgraphviz only seems to support the dot layout engine, not the neato engine. I tried 'layout=neato' (and some other fixes) and got this :  Error: Layout type: "neato" not recognized. Use one of: dot Layout was not done   - you have to use a local Graphviz or ??